# how to establish connectivity between my app running as a container with a database that is running on a different server

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-network

I have an application that is running as a container inside Linux based server that needs to be able to communicate with a DB server that is not containerized.

**Linux Server1 -> container -> app**

**Linux Server2 -> DB**

Both server1 and server2 are within the same network and able to ping each other.
Let's say server1 IP=10.X.*.* and server2 IP=10.X.*.*
and container IP is 172.*.*.*

Have tried exposing ports during docker run and tried firewall modifications.
created bridge network and tried with default host network as well

Expected: telnet  from server2 should return connected successfully output or similar

Comment: If you have a DNS, than add it to the net interface, otherwise you can use the DB IP address or add an entry into the resolve.conf.

Comment: Hi @max, thank you. 
tried adding DB server into resolve.conf but no luck.